# Compression of data during transfer to Google Cloud Coldline Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are using Google Coldline Storage for backing up and archiving certain data. We've been using gsutil rsync to basically mirror weekly the contents of a local directory with Google Coldline Storage Bucket and then at some point when the data is no longer needed, we leave it online and add an archive tag. It works well but now we want to compress the data that's on the coldline since we wouldn't be touching it much. Is it possible to compress the data that's now on the coldline storage using gsutil tools or it's too late and should have been done prior to upload?

A secondary compression question; gsutil cp has a compression flag (-z) which allows data to be compressed during file copy but gsutil rsync doesn't have that. So, say we gsutil cp data to coldline with compression but now we want to only rsync any changes with compression, how would this be handled if gsutil rsync does not have compression "on the fly" capabilities? Any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress data you have already uploaded, but doing that would entail creating a new object (the compressed one) and deleting the old (uncompressed) object. Depending on how long the old object has been around that could result in an [early deletion charge](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing) since you have stored the object using the Coldline storage class.

gsutil rsync does not support compression.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer has been very helpful. Will need to do a bit of math to see what it would cost. What tool would you recommend to use to do the compression on already uploaded data if we decide to go ahead?

Comment: I don't know of a tool to do specifically what you're trying to do. I think probably you'll need to implement some code on App Engine or Compute Engine to do it.

Comment: (http://googlegenomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases/compress_or_decompress_many_files/index.html) --> this seems like a tool we could use. In any case, we may have our in house team write some code to manage this. Thanks again.